# ASP.NET Application DLL Publishing Error Message

Tags: asp.net

I publish my ASP.NET application DLL manually via FTP. I'd love to be able to show the users a friendly error message while the DLL is being uploaded. I've tried the app_offline.htm thing (with the over 512 length). It works fine when my application's DLL is fine. But as soon as I delete the DLL or start copying over the DLL, then I get errors like

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebManagerSuite.Global_asax'.
```

Is there any way to have the friendly error message stay available while the main application DLL gets replaced?

Comment: Have you tried recycling the application pool *after* adding App_Offline.htm and *before* copying the DLL.

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks. Is there some way I should have know this? Or some explanation for it working that you might be able to give so I can understand why it works this way?

Comment: It may be a timing issue. If you set the App_Offline and immediately copy the DLL, the pool may not have time to adjust. You can try introducing a delay between setting the App_Offline and copying the DLL.

Comment: You can also review the settings on the pool in IIS manager. Some non-standard setting may be causing this behavior. The non-standard settings will be shown in bold face.